# Defining the array in VBA is giving Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

Tags: vbscript

test.vbs

```
dim myArray() as variant
```

when I ran cscript test.vbs it is giving the following error

*test.vbs(1, 15) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement*

Comment: your test.vbs has one row dim myArray() as variant ?

Comment: Probably, you are talking about VBS, not VBA?

Comment: VBA is not the same as VBS. Just  `dim myArray()` should be the correct way of writing it in vbs.

Comment: To add information; Unlike Visual Basic and Visual Basic for Applications, in which the developer can define the data type of a variable in advance, all variables in VBScript are variants.